# Imaguard plugin not working with ngnix server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx

We are using the [Imaguard](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imaguard/) WordPress plugin for some of my websites. One of those websites is on an Nginx server and the plugin doesn't seem to work there. I have followed the instructions mentioned here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/nginx-4?replies=9 but I'm still unable to get this plugin working.

It seems that those instructions will only work when we are hosting multiple websites on one server. We don't have a `vhost.conf` so I don't know where to add this code to the Nginx configuration:

```
if ($http_referer !~* "^http://(.+.)?cupidspulse.com"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    rewrite ^/(.*).(jpg|png|jpeg|gif)$ /show-image/?img=/$1.$2 redirect;
}
```

Where should I put this code to get this plugin working?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the link you gave, you should put this code in your `nginx.conf` file, if you aren't using multiple `.conf` files.

Comment: thanks michaelrmcneill for your prompt reply. I have tried putting this code in nginx.conf but by adding this code ngnix is not restarting. I think i have placed the code at wrong place in nginx.conf file. Please let me know the exact place where to add this code.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly without seeing your nginx.conf file. There is also a chance that the code that you have above possibly has a syntax error.

Comment: Just because you have used a converter, doesn't mean it validates, I'm not necessarily saying that is the problem, my point is, .htaccess files are for Apache, and sometimes you can't replicate the same exact functionality without manually rewriting.

Comment: thnks for your suggestion but i have converted this code by : http://winginx.com/en/htaccess but it is still not working. When I put this code in ngnix.conf file at the last it does not allow ngnix to restart. Appritiate your sudden help but still not working

Comment: What is the error that Nginx gives when you attempt to restart it?

Comment: I am doing this by commands and it is just showing ERROR when I run the command to restart ngnix.

Comment: What is the error though, Nginx gives information about the error when it fails to start.